# Change text of texview after rotation cancel my animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-2.2-froyo

I need change a textview's text after a rotation. I do this code to rotate my textview

```
RotateAnimation textAnim = new RotateAnimation(90, deg, text.getWidth() / 2, text.getHeight() / 2);
textAnim.setDuration(DURATION); 
textAnim.setFillAfter(true); 
text.startAnimation(textAnim);
```

After that, I need to change the text of the textview so I use setText on my textView.

When I do the setText my rotation is cancel.
My textview is just like before I rotate it.

Do you know why and how I can fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use  **AnimationListener** in your code.

And in the **onAnimationEnd()** change the text of the textview.
e.g.

```
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    textview.settext(" Your text");
}
```

Comment: I can't use animation listener because I need change text more than one time when a event occurred.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an animationListener to your animation and change the text in the textview inside `onAnimationEnd` method

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
}
```

});